# Save output to Hadoop in Spark Streaming with Aggregate

Tags: scala, hadoop, spark-streaming

I'm doing structured streaming with Spark. I'm trying to save the output of my query to the Hadoop system. But there is a dilemma: Because I'm using aggregate, I have to set the output mode as "complete", at the same time, file sink only works with parquet. Any workaround for this? Below are my codes:

```
val userSchema = new StructType().add("user1", "integer")
    .add("user2", "integer")
    .add("timestamp", "timestamp")
    .add("interaction", "string")

val tweets = spark
      .readStream
      .option("sep", ",")
      .schema(userSchema)
      .csv(streaming_path)

val windowedCounts = tweets.filter("interaction='MT'")
      .groupBy(
        window($"timestamp", "10 seconds", "10 seconds")
      ).agg(GroupConcat($"user2")).sort(asc("window"))

val query = windowedCounts.writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path", "partb_q2")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
  .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```